# DIVI text not showing on page because of Contact Form 7

Tags: html, css, wordpress, plugins

I’ve been using cf7 for a while now and I must say, good job!

At the moment the problem I’m experiencing is that any text I insert using Divi builder just vanishes and although the I-beam cursor still shows when going over the text I cant seem to find out the reason why the text doesn’t show (the text is located in the middle of the screen on the background image).

I’ve inspected suspected elements and found no luck within the css of both cf7 and divi.

I’ve removed and inserted the shortcode and the problem definitely resides within cf7

Any idea what the cause of this could be?

Comment: it seems some problem with the divi builder

Answer (score 0):

More information would be helpful. There might be a conflict between CF7 and Divi but that's not likely the case. Elegant Themes recognizes that CF7 is a super popular plugin and even wrote a blog post about how to style it.

Are you using a child theme? Did you make any customizations to your CSS, functions file, etc? Without being able to see the code it's much tougher to troubleshoot, even a screenshot would be better.